# Sharepoint: Sum Total of a List Columns using Content Editor

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have various lists in Sharepoint. We are looking to create various summary tables on other pages. So I am looking to fill the tables with various SUMS and COUNTS.

I am new to Javascript so I am starting with a basic SUM function.

I found a handy script (below). However, it seems to only sum the first 100 items only. Can someone assist?

```
<p id="SumPrices"></p>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     var listName = 'L&D';
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('GET', _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + 
           '/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(\'' + listName + '\')/items? 
            $select=Cost');
     xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json; odata=verbose');
     xhr.onload = function(){
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
           var results = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
           results = results.d.results;

           var sum = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
              sum += results[i].Cost;
             }

            document.getElementById('SumPrices').innerText = sum;
         }
          else {
            alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
          }
         };
       xhr.send();
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post what you've done so far to try to get this to work? That will help people better pinpoint your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lists are in same web, use rest api to access the list items.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetListsItems, "sp.js");
    });
    function GetListsItems() {
        var listName = 'L&D';

        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=Cost",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (result) {
                results = result.d.results;
                var sum = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    sum += results[i].Cost;
                }

                document.getElementById('SumPrices').innerText = sum;
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The lists are in the same web. Your script provided the same result. It only returned the sum for the first 100 items. The list has 252 entries. 'results.length' seems be equal to 100

Comment: Add /items?$select=Cost&$top=1000 if you want to retrieve more than 100 items.